# Is there a name or symbol for continuous and bounded functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, notation

For example, I have a function $f$ that is continuous and satisfies $|f| \leq M \lt \infty$

Is there a succinct notation to decribe this function without having to specify continuity and boundedness separately?

Comment: The space of continuous bounded functions defined on some domain $A$ is usuallydenoted by $C_b(A)$. So, if $f$ is defined over the reals I would write simply $f \in C_b (\Bbb{R})$.

Comment: Worth noting in this context is the terminology $$C_c (X) \subset C_0 (X) \subset C_b(X) \subset C^0(X)$$ of continuous functions with compact supprt, continuous decaying functions, continuous bounded functions and continuous functions. They all coincide for $X$ compact.